# Why do_shortcode is not executing the shortcode in data-* html attributes?

Tags: shortcode

This is on Vanilla installation. I've made a shortcode:-

```
/**
 * Creates a shortcode for shortcode_use_here
 * @author Omar Tariq <XXXXXX@gmail.com>
 */
function callback_banana_abc( $args ){
    /* Don't echo! Always return */

    return 'yay!'; 
}
add_shortcode( 'banana_abc', 'callback_banana_abc' );
```

And I've made a template that looks like this:-

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Test Template
 * Description: Hello world.
 */


$str = '<a href="#" title="[banana_abc]" data-abc="[banana_abc]">[banana_abc]</a>';
echo do_shortcode($str);
```

The output is:-

```
<a href="#" title="yay!" data-abc="[banana_abc]">yay!</a>
```

This is only for data-* attributes. It works fine when used in `title` attribute.

Comment: It works for me but that is a very peculiar shortcode. You are doing a lot of work to process that string.

Comment: @s_ha_dum The original shortcode where I experienced this problem is not only a string display. I made this small code that regenerates the error for me. After reading your comment, I downloaded wordpress again, pasted the shortcode code in twentyfifteen's functions.php. Made a new template and pasted the above mentioned page template code. Still, I got the same results. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/sJLhkN2.png

Comment: `a herf` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @Aibrean That's typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`do_shortcodes_in_html_tags()` runs attributes through `wp_kses_one_attr()` which checks them against `wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' )` which by default only accepts standard non-data attributes, so you'd have to add your attribute:

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', function ( $allowedposttags, $context ) {
    if ( $context == 'post' ) {
        $allowedposttags['a']['data-abc'] = 1;
    }
    return $allowedposttags;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: `"An expert is one who knows more and more about less and less" `

Comment: Ha excellent !!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem but the way you are using the shortcode to construct small pieces of that string is making me crazy. Try this, and maybe it will work around your problem as well:

```
function callback_banana_abc( $args ){
  $atts = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
      'title' => 'yay!',
      'data' => 'yay!',
      'linktext' => 'yay!'
    ), 
    $args
  );
  $str = '<a href="#" title="'.$atts['title'].'" data-abc="'.$atts['data'].'">'.$atts['linktext'].'</a>';
  return $str; 
}
add_shortcode( 'banana_abc', 'callback_banana_abc' );

$str = '[banana_abc]';
echo do_shortcode($str);

$str = '[banana_abc title="ba" data="na" linktext="na"]';
echo do_shortcode($str);
```

Comment: Don't do_shortcode https://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/