# Shortcode not working inside html input

Tags: shortcode

I'm using Wordpress `4.2.3`

The shortcode is added with the following:

```
function upsellxid_shortcode() {
    return '9eaa86d1a36a126313aa752c2ff8e16c';
}

function upsellxid_shortcode_2() {
    return '4849f6a5e3b188fa4b3b4c1f37975706';
}

function upsellxid_shortcode_rsa() {
    return '7a9bc3b332605817594dbac27847dff0';
}

function infusionsoftEmail_shortcode() {
    // Code
    $in = $_REQUEST;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
        $parse = parse_url($_REQUEST['q']);
        parse_str($parse['query'], $get);
        $in = $get;
    }

    $email = false;
    if (isset($in['inf_field_Email']) == true &&  empty($in['inf_field_Email']) == false) {
        $email = $in['inf_field_Email'];
    } else if(isset($in['Contact0Email']) == true &&  empty($in['Contact0Email']) == false) {
        $email = $in['Contact0Email'];
    }
    return $email;
}
add_shortcode('upsellxid', 'upsellxid_shortcode');
add_shortcode('xid_RSAMonthly', 'upsellxid_shortcode_2');
add_shortcode('rsa30daytrial', 'upsellxid_shortcode_rsa');
add_shortcode('infusionsoftEmail', 'infusionsoftEmail_shortcode');
```

Using it in a post seems fine (just `[rsa30daytrial]` will output the correct code). But using it inside an html input returns the raw text:

```
[rsa30daytrial]
[rsa30daytrial]
<input type="text" value="[rsa30daytrial]" />
```

results in (page source):

```
<p>7a9bc3b332605817594dbac27847dff0
7a9bc3b332605817594dbac27847dff0
<input type="text" value="[rsa30daytrial]" /></p>
```

Comment: Follow this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195673/22728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As above, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195673/22728 solved it:

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', function ( $allowedposttags, $context ) {
    if ( $context == 'post' ) {
        $allowedposttags['input']['value'] = 1;
    }
    return $allowedposttags;
}, 10, 2 );
```