# Shortcodes in billing fields doesn't work

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, input, geo-data

WooCommerce: 3.5.1
WordPress: 4.9.8

I want to set automaticly billing fields with data from GeoIP shortcodes, but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );

function set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = '[geoip_detect2 property="city"]';
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['default'] = '[geoip_detect2 property="mostSpecificSubdivision"]';
    return $fields;
}
```

This solution didn't help: [Shortcode not working inside html input](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195707/shortcode-not-working-inside-html-input)

Output

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_city" id="billing_city" placeholder="" value="[geoip_detect2 property=&quot;city&quot;]" autocomplete="address-level2">
```

Comment: You can use `do_shortcode()` - e.g. `do_shortcode( '[geoip_detect2 property="city"]' )`, instead of adding the shortcodes "as-is" to the `$fields` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" answer is that you need to use `do_shortcode()` to process the shortcode as you can't just simply apply a shortcode within the code.  Here's your original code with the "official" `do_shortcode()` way:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );

function set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = do_shortcode( '[geoip_detect2 property="city"]' );
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['default'] = do_shortcode( '[geoip_detect2 property="mostSpecificSubdivision"]' );
    return $fields;
}
```

While that approach *will* parse the shortcode, I personally would suggest that you **NOT** use `do_shortcode()` because it has to run through [a fairly extensive regex to process](https://konstantin.blog/2013/dont-do_shortcode/).  It's better to find the actual callback function for the shortcode in question and use that directly. Yes, sometimes that is difficult, and is tricky in some situations. But thankfully, there's [a good article and a better solution at this link](https://codesymphony.co/dont-do_shortcode/).

So here's how to do it the J.D. Grimes way (as discussed in the article, and including his utility function along with your code snippet revised to use it):

```
/**
 * Call a shortcode function by tag name.
 *
 * @author J.D. Grimes
 * @link https://codesymphony.co/dont-do_shortcode/
 *
 * @param string $tag     The shortcode whose function to call.
 * @param array  $atts    The attributes to pass to the shortcode function. Optional.
 * @param array  $content The shortcode's content. Default is null (none).
 *
 * @return string|bool False on failure, the result of the shortcode on success.
 */
function do_shortcode_func( $tag, array $atts = array(), $content = null ) {

    global $shortcode_tags;

    if ( ! isset( $shortcode_tags[ $tag ] ) )
        return false;

    return call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[ $tag ], $atts, $content, $tag );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );

function set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = do_shortcode_func( 'geoip_detect2', array( 'property' => "city" ) );
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['default'] = do_shortcode_func( 'geoip_detect2', array( 'property' => "mostSpecificSubdivision" ) );
    return $fields;
}
```

Either way is "right" and should solve the issue (at least as far as the shortcode parsing goes).  Hope this helps you.