# Wordpress 4.3 broke meta redirect (with url params plugin)

Tags: plugins, redirect

I'm using the plugin URL Params ([homepage](http://www.asandia.com/wordpress-plugins/urlparams/)) in order to send an URL to a page and after three seconds redirect the user to that page. Unfortunately Wordpress 4.3 broke that functionality.

This is how it was done:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=[urlparam param="link"]">
```

The redirect only redirects the user to http://www.sitename.com/redirect/[urlparam%20param=

A work around is putting a link and placing it like this but then I loose the auto redirect.

```
<a href='[urlparam param="link"]'>
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite the meta tag so that the redirect could work?

Comment: Plugin only add shortcode, but not execute it as far as i see. I don't see how it was even working before 4.3

Comment: can you pass the code, which is generating the <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=[urlparam param="link"]">

Comment: @websuporter I might missunderstand you but the meta lin is copied directly from the Wordpress page. As you see it here is just how it looks. The URL with the parameters look like this: http://www.example.com/redirect/?company=Industrypartner&link=http://www.example.com/business-consulting/enterprise-resource&area=Consulting&solution=iConsulting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the content attribute of a meta tag to contain a shortcode, eg in your "functions.php" add:

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', function ( $allowedposttags, $context ) {
    if ( $context == 'post' ) {
        $allowedposttags['meta']['content'] = 1;
    }
    return $allowedposttags;
}, 10, 2 );
```

and then your original **(without the quotes in `param=link`)**

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=[urlparam param=link]">
```

should work.

Comment: That line of code redirects me to the following URL: http://www.example.com/redirect/%3C?php%20echo%20$_REQUEST[%27link%27];%20?%3E

Comment: That looks as if the php is being escaped, and hence not being parsed, use a text editor to add the code to whatever file you're editing...

Comment: I guess I should be using the code when editing a php file, I added it in the editor mode. Any chance of getting this to work from the editor? Editing the physical files is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm I just copied & pasted that line into my "header.php" using the Appearance > Editor and it worked fine - what is /redirect pointing to?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that I add this to a page (post type page) not ot the code fiel behind.

Comment: Oh right I'm with you - I didn't realize you could do that (put a meta outside the head) - but anyway the way around it is to allow the shortcode in the tag (see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195673/57034) - I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: Ok after around 6 goes it seems to work - but for WP to parse the shortcode you need to lose the quotes around `link` in the `param=link` bit.

Comment: Works just fine now! Thank you for taking your time to help me on this - highly appreciated!

Comment: Everything is workoing fine with the code I got from you except one crucial part: If the url contains an "&" sign then everything after that is removed. Can that be fixed, would really mean a lot to get this to work. Example: www.domain.com/?test=yes&param=yes. This would redirect to www.domain.com/?test=yes. Any chance you know what is going wrong?

Comment: That will get separated into 2 query vars, `link`, and `param`. Encoding the ampersand with `%26` seems to work, eg `?link=http://www.domain.com/?test=yes%26param=yes` - you could try that...

Comment: That was an easy fix, never thought of that. Thank you for helping me once again!